# HTML button launch Shell script

Tags: php, lighttpd

Working with:

- Linux Debian
- Lighttpd Server
- PHP7.0

I want to launch some shell scripts pressing HTML buttons.
All the files are placed in /var/www/html
The rights are done by:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

So, I wrote some code:

HTML test code (index.html):

```
<form action="openApp.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Open Script">
</form>
```

PHP test code (openApp.php):

```
<?php
    exec('nautilus');
    header('Location: http://localhost/index.html?success=true');
?>
```

But no luck, nothing is working.

Also, my Lighttpd configuration file is like that:

> server.modules = (
>       "mod_access",
>       "mod_alias",
>       "mod_compress",
>       "mod_fastcgi",
>       "mod_redirect",
>   )

May be I am wrong with that piece of code.
Do I need some Javascript to do the job ?
May be the rights are wrong ?

Could you help me please ? I am stuck with that.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? Your script is probably working, it's just not doing what you think

Comment: Hi Blues, No the script as you can see might launch Nautilus, but it doesn't.
This is why I don't understand what going on. Do you think it's a problem with rights or may be in the wrong directory ? Thanks for your help

Comment: I am with @blues  Nautilus is a GUI file manager.  Without setting DISPLAY where do you think it is going to launch the GUI?  The PHP might try exporting environment DISPLAY=0.0 before launching Nautilus.  The PHP should also exec it in the background, and backgrounded, and in a separate process group, or else it will be killed when the CGI exits.

Comment: Hi Gstrauss, thanks for your feedback. I did some test where I modified the shell script to create an empty file "touch /home/$USER/testFile". The solution doesn't work, even if there is no GUI. But according to your answer, I am agree with both of you, your are right. So, could you tell me if I did some error on the HTML page ? May be using POST method ? May be with some wrongs rights ? Thanks for your help and support